Python subclasses function
I have an abstract class defined (BaseClass). And then I define a subclass in a different "folder" or file (SubClass).
In my "main" function, I try to check what are the subclasses of the base class. Ideally, I was hoping it would show me all the subclasses regardless of where they are. However, python shows me an empty list.
If I move the subclass into the same file as the baseclass, then subclasses shows the list properly.
# base.py

import abc

class BaseClass(abc.ABC):
    
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def hello():
        ...
        
class SubClass2(BaseClass):
    
    def hello():
        print("Hello Child2")

# sub_class.py

from base import BaseClass

class SubClass(BaseClass):
    
    def hello():
        print("Hello Child")

# main.py

from base import BaseClass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(BaseClass.__subclasses__())

Here is an example to demo: https://www.online-python.com/gckwbpi9aQ
Further strangeness. If I try to import the missing child in the main file and check its ancestors; lo and behold, subclasses returns the right results
# main.py but importing the missing subclass

from base import BaseClass
from sub_class import SubClass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(BaseClass.__subclasses__())
    print(SubClass.__mro__)

I have been trying hard to find documentation on why this behaves the way it does, but I'm pretty sure I'm missing something super basic.
Use case I'm trying to accomplish.
Following from this solution in typer where we want to create dynamic commands: https://github.com/tiangolo/typer/issues/257, I wanted to create a base class that folks can extend. And any concrete subclass could then be added into the command structure at runtime.
Maybe the incorrect assumption I had in my head was that all classes are loaded ahead of time.


sub_class.py is never executed unless it is imported somewhere. How do you expect it to know you wrote that source code otherwise?

What are you trying to accomplish exactly? Like, why does it matter that BaseClass has a subclass that's never used? Beware the XY problem.

You mean, in the python world, unless there is an import statement somewhere, the class is never loaded? The use case I was attempting is to dynamically create a list of commands. The folks who want to write a new command would simply implement the base class. There is no more wiring to be done. The subclass would be used but not directly via imports

Of course.  Python only executes the lines it reads.  If no one imports it, the interpreter will never see the file.  This is true of any compiler.

I believe it works like this in most languages‽ Usually a runtime or compiler doesn’t willy nilly import all files in a folder without being told to do so.

@wjandrea edited the question to add the actual use-case. I need to create a list of commands without having end-users of the module having to wire it elsewhere. The ideal result would be; if I need to add a new command, simply create a subclass and write the code. The command will get registered automagically.

Not true for jvm languages, but it is also true that the classloading is probably very different. In the sense, it's pretty normal in let's say java, to have a main function just list out the entire hierarchy of a base class without any base class imports. (That's the whole basis for reflection). But I reckon this is possible because the classloader loads all classes in the classpath. Like a java project similar to the python project would load all files in the classpath.

This was solved in part by using an approach highlighted here. Which tbf, has been explained by @juanpa.arrivillaga.
However, instead of blindly loading and comparing with globals(), the mods that were made is to dynamically import classes that are required rather than everything in the namespace.
So within the section where we add the object to globals, we can do a check similar to
if isinstance(v, type) and not inspect.isabstract(v) and issubclass(v, <yourbaseclass):
    globals()[obj] = imported_module.__dict__[obj]

Post dynamically loading these objects, __subclasses__() returns the required information.
